# Why is my Python speech-recognition code not calling the callback function during background audio listening?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

im trying to listen to audio in background as my script is running i have this part of code which is used for listening

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pyautogui
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()
def callback(recognizer, audio):
    print('go')
    # received audio data, now we'll recognize it using Google Speech Recognition
    try:
        print("fun trig")

        # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
        # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
        # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
        print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()
# print(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names())
with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)  # we only need to calibrate once, before we start listening

# start listening in the background (note that we don't have to do this inside a `with` statement)
stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
# `stop_listening` is now a function that, when called, stops background listening

# do some unrelated computations for 5 seconds
for _ in range(50): time.sleep(0.1)   # we're still listening even though the main thread is doing other things

# calling this function requests that the background listener stop listening
stop_listening(wait_for_stop=False)

# do some more unrelated things
while True: 
    print('gone') 
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

after a while im getting "gone" printed neither go got printed nor "fun trig" that means callback function was not called

Comment: After a while you call stop_listening

Comment: If you need help, please copy a minimal [working code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is sr doing in you code? Have you forgotten the import?

Comment: I have edited the code now you can look at imports and sr

Answer (score -1):

**Try This. Tell me if it works ?**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def callback(recognizer, audio):

    try:     
        print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()  

with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)

while True:
    input('unrelated input ...')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: same result just getting "unrelated input" printed to screen